# Format json query output so that it would give a list of paths using ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have a registered output with ansible that looks like this:

```
- debug:
var: activemq_files | json_query('results[*].files[*].path')

    ok: [localhost] => {
    "activemq_files | json_query('results[*].files[*].path')": [
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar"
        ],
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/activemq-client-5.15.9.jar"
        ],
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/activemq-kahadb-store-5.15.9.jar"
        ],
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar"
        ],
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar"
        ],
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.jar"
        ],
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/hawtbuf-1.11.jar",
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/optional/hawtbuf-proto-1.11.jar"
        ],
        [
        "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar"
        ],
        [
            "/home/activemq/activemq/lib/optional/activeio-core-3.1.4.jar"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I would like in the output to only get a list of path without all those square brackets so that I could use it with the synchronize module to fetch the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the output through one more filter to get a flat list:

```
- debug:
    var: activemq_files | json_query('results[*].files[*].path') | flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem

```
- debug:
    var: activemq_files | json_query('results[].files[].path
```